# How to download a file from Json by xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, download, blob

I want to receive a file from `Json` through xmlHttpRequest, but the desired file cannot be opened after downloading.

**The desired file that is stored in the database has no problem because when I save it in C#, it opens it, the problem is only in the java script part that does not receive the desired file correctly.**

**Java Script:**

```
var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlHttpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('request.Id', window.$(this).attr('data'));
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", 'Url', true);

xmlHttpRequest.onloadend = function () {
        let response = ParseJson(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);

        alert(response.Result);

        let blob = new Blob([response.File], { type: response.MimeType }); 

        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        a.download = response.FileName;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
}
xmlHttpRequest.send(formData);
```

**Controller:**

```
public IActionResult GetFileDownload(GetFileDownloadRequest request)
{
       //Get byte[] from database

       return Json(new GetFileDownload()
       {
              Result = "OK",
              FileName = file.Name ?? "",
              MimeType = Path.GetExtension(file.Name).GetMimeType(),
              File = file.File
       });
}
```

Comment: Why not create file stream in your asp code and put json in file and then just download it?

Comment: Can you explain with an example?@speed258

Comment: I have other objects inside Json, I put them here as a summary.@speed258

Comment: Could you post GetFileDownloadRequest entity?

Comment: My problem is in the **response** part, which does not receive the byte[] correctly, the request works correctly.@QiangFu

Answer (score 0):

Json response initial letter will become lowercase instead of upcase. So it will be `response.mimeType` `response.file` `response.fileName`.
You can try the following code for a test
GetFileDownload.cs

```
    public class GetFileDownload
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string MimeType { get; set; }
        public byte[] File { get;set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
        [HttpGet("DownloadFile")]
        public IActionResult DownloadFile()
        {
            var path = Path.Combine("E:\\Sample.xlsx"); 
            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path); //get bytes


            var contentType = "";
            new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(path, out contentType);


            var result = new GetFileDownload()
            {
                Result = "OK",
                FileName = "Sample.xlsx",
                MimeType = contentType,
                File = bytes
            };
            return result == null ? NotFound() : Ok(result);
        }
```

Script

```
<script>
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://localhost:7011/api/values/downloadfile',true) 
    xhr.onloadend = function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            let response = JSON.parse(this.response);
            console.log(response);
            let blob = new Blob([response.file], { type: response.mimeType }); 
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            a.download = response.fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

F12
[image]

Comment: The method has a request and the method type is Post, and as I said, the file is downloaded but not opened